# README-ja.md / README.ja.md のような、同じファイルを言語別に作成する形式について詳しく知りたいです。

Tags: markdown

READMEなどのドキュメントを複数の言語に翻訳する際のやり方について、少なくとも2つメジャーなやり方があるように見受けられました。

#### 1. README-ja.md （ファイル名に含める）

例: https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/dev/docs/ja/README-ja.md

#### 2. README.ja.md （2つ目の拡張子にする）

例: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/README.ja.md

#### 質問

これらについて、（おそらくは好みだと思うものの）どちらを採用すべきかの意見を教えていただきたいです（メジャーなXXXのプロジェクトではこちら、YYYのライブラリの恩恵を受けるならこちら、など）

Comment: GitHubでフォルダを開いた際のREADMEとして表示される方を選ぼうと思って比べてみましたが、README-ja.md と README.ja.md のいずれも README扱いされませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

例えば `gcc` などではどちらでもない手段となっていて
`gcc-11.2.0/gcc/po/ja.po`
`gcc-11.2.0/gcc/po/es.po`
`gcc-11.2.0/gcc/po/fr.po`
`gcc-11.2.0/gcc/po/zh-CN.po`
`gcc-11.2.0/libcpp/po/ja.po`
`gcc-11.2.0/libcpp/po/zh_Tw.po`
のようにメッセージディレクトリの下に各国語ファイルが配置されています。

`find` 等でメッセージファイルを探す際に `find . -name '*.md'` としたいであろうことから `README.md.ja` のように「拡張子が変わる」運用としないほうがよさそう以外に規則はなさそう・・

自分で作るプロジェクトでは自分で命名規則を決めて明文化しておけばOKでしょう。